# Promise.all() not working with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have a `VPService.requestQueue` which is an array of objects with the following content:

[image]

I need to do something after all promises have been completed so I'm using `Promise.all(VPService.requestQueue).then(...)` but its not working.

I tried making an array of both the `canceller` and `promise` and then calling `Promise.all()` on both of then both the console.logs inside this `Promise.all()` gets called BEFORE I receive the response from the promise.

```
        //getting an array of the promises from VPService.requestQueue
        var requestQueuePromises = VPService.requestQueue.map(function (queue) {
            return queue.canceller.promise;
        });
        //gettin array of cancellers
        var requestQueueCancellers = VPService.requestQueue.map(function (queue) {
            return queue.canceller;
        });
```

Now use Promise.all() to know when the promises have ended but both console.logs are being printed before my promises results are received.

```
        Promise.all(requestQueueCancellers).then(function () {
            console.log("After all cancellers")
        });
        Promise.all(requestQueuePromises).then(function () {
            console.log("After all promises")
        });
```

Comment: The cancelers look like Deferred objects, which not being thenable aren't valid for use with `Promise.all`. But you shouldn't need to do those anyway, if you're doing their promises. Can you put a [mcve] in the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) to make it runnable?

Comment: Does the `promise` object, under `canceller`, have `then` function ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for answer. Sorry but the code behind all this is quite long and complex.  So is there any way to stop ongoing deferreds ? I tried `canceller.resolve()` but the first deferred us always executed if not is there any way to wait to do something until al deferreds are finished?

Comment: @Oskar yes they do

Comment: @CodingMcCodington: The point of a [mcve] is to trim the problem down to a reasonable size. See the link for details, but the point is: Usually you figure it out in the process, and if you don't, you have something contained you can ask for help with.

Comment: @CodingMcCodington: Again: Why `Promise.all` on the cancelers when you're using `Promise.all` on their promises?

Comment: @CodingMcCodington why not use Angular's promise with `$q`?

Comment: @tanmay yup that is actually how the promises are being created: `var canceller = $q.defer();
            factory.requestQueue.push({
                url: config.api + 'timelinedata/' + params,
                canceller: canceller
            });`

Comment: @CodingMcCodington so handle them with `$q.all(...)`